# How to add roll in camera class

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I am building a camera class and have taken help from the online tutorials for building this class.

Now i want to add roll in the camera and could not find any reading material which would explain how to add Roll in camera.

```
Camera(glm::vec3 position = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 500.0f), glm::vec3 up = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), float yaw = YAW, float pitch = PITCH) : Front(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f)), Zoom(ZOOM)
    {
        Position = position;
        WorldUp = up;
        Yaw = yaw;
        Pitch = pitch;
        updateCameraVectors();
    }

glm::mat4 GetViewMatrix()
    {
        return glm::lookAt(Position, Position + Front , Up);
    }

void updateCameraVectors()
    {
        
        glm::vec3 front;
        front.x = cos(glm::radians(Yaw - 90)) * cos(glm::radians(Pitch));
        front.y = sin(glm::radians(Pitch));
        front.z = sin(glm::radians(Yaw - 90)) * cos(glm::radians(Pitch)) ;
        Front = glm::normalize(front);
        Right = glm::normalize(glm::cross(Front, WorldUp));
        Up = glm::normalize(glm::cross(Right, Front));
    }
```

I would be thankful if someone can explain how to add ROll in this class or guide me to some reading material.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To [roll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_principal_axes#Longitudinal_axis_(roll)) the view, you have rotate the up vector (`Up`) around the line of sight (`Front`).

Define a rotation matrix around `Front` by `Roll`:

```cpp
glm::mat4 roll_mat = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::radians(Roll), Front);
```

Transform the `Up` vector by the matrix:

```cpp
Up = glm::mat3(roll_mat) * Up;
```

Comment: Thank you , i  did try multiplying the rotation matrix to the Front vector but never thought of applying that matrix to Roll.

Comment: Thanks Helped :)